# Is there a matplotlib equivalent for printing nice tables in python?

Tags: python, pandas

Does anyone know if there is a way of creating nice looking tables in Python? I'm thinking similar to matplotlib for charting, but for tables?

Many thanks.

Comment: Does this help? https://plot.ly/python/table/

Comment: Yes it does actually thanks a lot mate